# Read any number of bits from ifstream

Tags: c++, bit

I'm currently working with SWFFiles. 
In SWF headers ist RECT, which is built with 5 fields. First one is 5bit field(nBits -> used to specify length of others fields.

[image: Rectangle record]

How should look like a method, which takes one argument(how many bits read) and reads it from `ifstream`?

[SWF File format specification](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf)

Thanks, S.

Answer (score 0):

C++ file streams are byte-oriented. You can't read specific numbers of bits from them (unless the number is a multiple of 8 of course).

To get just 5 bits, you'll have to read an entire byte and then mask off the 8 bits of interest. If that byte also holds another field you'll have to keep it around for use later. If you make this generic enough, you could write your own "bit stream" class that buffers unused portions of bytes internally.

To obtain the low-order (least significant) 5 bits of a byte:

```
unsigned char bits = byte & 0x1F; // note 0x1F = binary 00011111
```

To obtain the high-order (most significant) 5 bits:

```
unsigned char bits = byte >> 3; // shift off the unused 3 low bits
```

Comment: could you please show some code for how to extract bit values from say a double?

Comment: @Cool_Coder I don't think you want to do anything with doubles, but see edit above for code to get bits from the low or high end (which end is used will depend on the file format).